# Where Web SQL database file located in phonegap android app

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, web-sql

I am developing a android application using phonegap.
i am using WebSQL database using persistenceJS .its configuration is as follow

persistence.store.cordovasql.config(
            persistence,
            'mydb',
            '0.0.1',
            'My App Database',
            5 * 1024 * 1024,
            0
        );

where can I find 'mydb.db' file from android native

Answer (score 0):

To get the db file,

> Android Device monitor -> File Explorer -> data -> data ->
>   yourpackagename ->app_webview -> you can find the file.